# Magento 1.9.2.2 acees denied in vendor login with supee patches?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am new in magento in 1.9.2.2 my market place extension vendor login access denied in vendor login i have found there is some acl problem but i am not able to change it Please help

[image]

```
<acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <medma>
                            <title>Medma</title>                            
                            <children>
                                <marketplace>
                                    <title>Market Place</title>                                 
                                    <children>
                                        <pending_products>
                                            <title>Pending Products</title>                                         
                                        </pending_products>
                                        <manage_vendors>
                                            <title>Manage Vendors</title>                                           
                                        </manage_vendors>
                                        <reviews_ratings>
                                            <title>Reviews and Ratings</title>                                          
                                            <children>                                  
                                                <pending_reviews>
                                                    <title>Pending Reviews</title>                                                  
                                                </pending_reviews>
                                                <all_reviews>
                                                    <title>All Reviews</title>                                                  
                                                </all_reviews>                                      
                                                <manage_ratings>
                                                    <title>Manage Ratings</title>                                                   
                                                </manage_ratings>
                                            </children>
                                        </reviews_ratings>
                                        <manage_verification>
                                            <title>Verification</title>                                         
                                            <children>
                                                <manage_type>
                                                    <title>Manage Types</title>                                                 
                                                </manage_type>
                                            </children>                                                
                                        </manage_verification>
                                        <configuration>
                                            <title>Configuration</title>                                            
                                        </configuration>
                                    </children>
                                </marketplace>                    
                            </children>
                        </medma>            
                        <vendor>
```

how to I change acl property in my extension thanks for advance

Comment: i change in controller also but nothing happen

Comment: Magento Admin question on a third party module. You probably need to contact the developer (Medma) and ask for an upgrade to the newest version. While ACL is one of the issues, there are probably two other things that need to be fixed before it will  be fully functional.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to make any changes for ACL then you can simply write below code in respective controllers.

> protected function _isAllowed()
>       {
>       return true;
>       }